# Is there any benefit to sending out a Bean Bottle from Poké Pelago?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I've sent out a few bottles of 7 beans from the Poké Pelago and received one bottle with 7 beans myself.

Is there any advantage to sending out bottles of beans or is it a gift mechanic for a randomly selected player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the page for [Poké Pelago on Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokepelago.shtml), it looks like this is just to help random players over the Internet. It won't give you any benefit except the joy of knowing that you helped a stranger.

> You can also, once a day, send out a Bean Bottle. This will put 7 of your standard beans out and distribute them across the Internet to other players and you will sometimes find Bean Bottles from other players turn up on your game.

Comment: From memory (I can't go back and check) Mohn first suggested that when you send bottles of beans, good fortune may come your way, or something to that effect. Additionally, he refuses to let you send more than one bottle a day. If this is a random gifting mechanic, why restrict you to sending one bottle a day?

Comment: There is no supporting evidence at this point that sending bean bottles has any in game benefit to the player. I'm putting this down to misinterpretation of Mohn's dialogue and marking this as answered.

Comment: @PhilD. I would disagree, I've only ever recieved bean bottles when I've sent them out. If I don't send any out, I do not receive them. So unless you're sending beans out, I don't think you are eligible to receive any either. In the end, if a player sends out a bottle, they have a chance of receiving more bottles in return, giving the sending player a net positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

On days when I send bean bottles, it seems like I have more pokemon trying to come to my island for me to "see if they will go into a ball". I thought it was supposed to boost luck on your island.

Answer (score -3):

On days that I send one I will find at least three bottles washed up on the beach. They usually have rare beans in them.